# "global participants" vs "international participants"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

What is the correct way of saying that I participated in  competitions that had participants from across the globe? I also have to be brief, saying it.

The sentence I am using in this case is:

> (I) Ranked 22nd of 2062 **global participants** in Women’s Cup, October
>   2015.

*International* generally means *not national*. I want to say that national as well as international participants were involved in the competition.

- Would the word *[international](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/international)* be a better choice instead of the word  *[global](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/global)*?

Comment: You might consider the differences between *global* (around the globe) and *nation*. *global* makes no distinction for political boundaries. In your case, anywhere on Earth vs. any nation/country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are looking for is

> global

since it also includes you home country.

> international

would refer to all other countries except your home country.

This usage is applied to financial products where, as a US investor,

> a global portfolio

would have investments throughout the world including the US, and

> an international portfolio

would have investment throughout the world excluding the US.

For a British investor the terms would include or exclude UK holdings.